# My BCC in php mail script is not working, kindly assist

Tags: php, mailer

Please help, my BCC isn't working.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

```
$to = "recepient@email.com";
        $subject = "A message came in from the Website:";

        $message ='{$message}';

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r \n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r \n";
        $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: myemail@email.com' . " \r\n"; //<- this part is not working :(

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Try putting it in double quotes

Comment: You also need to change your `Content-type` to `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Plus that `space` before your `" \r\n"` could also be playing a role. Consult: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred!  I managed to have it working by deleting the spaces between \r\n in headers and by changing the BCC line into $headers .= "Bcc: myemail@email.com\r\n";

Comment: I take it my comments helped then?

Comment: Yes Fred...how do I accept your comment as the best answer?  Sorry, newbie here :)

Comment: Glad it did the trick. I'll post an answer and you can click on the "checkmark" to accept as an answer. Cheers ;)

Comment: Gave you a couple extra points too. All the best Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space before your `" \r\n"` seems to be at fault.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred! I managed to have it working by deleting the spaces between \r\n in headers and by changing the BCC line into $headers .= "Bcc: myemail@email.com\r\n";

Rock on! :)

Comment: Anytime ;-) Glad I could be of help.